# convolution of two probability densities in MatLab

Tags: density-function, convolution

I am considering two exponential probability distribution functions with mean equal to 5 and 3.

```
pdf1=@(x)exppdf(x,5);
pdf2=@(x)exppdf(x,3);
```

I want to compute the pdf of the sum of these two densities using convolution:

```
x=0:100;
uh=conv(pdf1(x),pdf2(x));
```

Since the step-size of x is one, uh should be a density and the area under uh should be one.
But

```
trapz(0:200,uh)
```

yields 1.26.

But when I choose x=0:0.1:100;

```
trapz(0:0.1:200,uh)*0.1
```

yields 1.026.

So, it turns out that the accuracy of 'using 'conv' to the get the density of the sum of two independent random variables' depends heavily upon the support chosen. Am I doing it correct or there is something wrong with my approach? Is there an automatic way to select a reasonable support for the convolution of two desities?

P.S. I am not sure but this doesn't seem like an off-topic question as it also involves a question about selection of an optimal step-size.

Comment: did you check how `conv` is handling the data at the edges of the range of `x`? That could lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: No, I didn't check that. But I don't understand what do you mean and how to check it?

Comment: Check out the `shape` argument, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html. If you don't specify it, it takes the value `full`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: This does not seem to be working in my case. Unfortunately, I don't understand why this can even create a problem? I guess I need full convolution.

Comment: more explanations at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26079/why-does-the-amplitude-of-a-discrete-convolution-depend-on-the-time-step

Comment: From the discussion on that forum, it seems like my approach is correct and the step-size indeed matters when approximating continuous convolution integral by its discrete counterpart. But the questions remains how do I automatically select the optimal step-size.

Comment: Step size might matter a tiny bit, but the problem rests on a fundamental misconception: you are assuming that if $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx = 1$, then $$(dx) \left(\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i\, dx)\right)=1$$ for small increments like $dx=1$ or $dx=1/10$. That's not the case: as $dx\to 0$, the sums of course converge to $1$ but are always larger.

Comment: That is helpful. But then question remains how do I select a dx in MatLab so that it gives reasonably accurate results.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: @confunded I used analytical expressions for the convolution of two exponential pdfs.